# Add navigation node that points to /_layouts/15/search.aspx to search navigation

Tags: search-results, modern-experience

In our SharePoint Online tenant, we have quite a large amount of team sites using the classic experience where the site collection feature *SharePoint Lists and Libraries experience* is enabled.

Nevertheless, we would like to promote modern search. Therefore, I wanted to replace the search navigation nodes "Everything" and "This Site" with navigation nodes pointing to the following two URLs:

- /_layouts/15/search.aspx/siteall
- /_layouts/15/search.aspx

However, there is one issue that prevents me from implementing this change: these pages expect the query to be passed as value of the URL parameter q whereas the search box in the top right corner passes the query as value of the URL parameter k.

Did anybody find a solution for this yet?

Comment: on-prem or O365 Online?

Comment: @willman Sorry, I forgot to mention that we're talking about SharePoint Online here. I updated my question accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

You need to do a coded redirect.  Choose a **classic** site that all of your users have at least read access to.  Open that site in SharePoint Designer.  In a page library on that site, create a new .aspx page in SharePoint Designer.  Edit it in advanced mode and replace the entire contents with this:

```
<%@ Language=C# %>
<HTML>
<script language="c#" runat="server">
  protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
    string targetSearchUrl = "/_layouts/15/search.aspx"
    if (Request.Params["k"] != null)
      targetSearchUrl += "?q=" + Request.Params["k"];

    HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect(targetSearchUrl, true);
  }
</script>
<body></body>
</HTML>
```

Now point the search navigation node to this new redirector page instead of directly to `/_layouts/15/search.aspx`.  You probably have to create a separate everything-redirector to redirect to `/_layouts/15/search.aspx/siteall`.

Comment: Thank you, I'll give that a try and let you know the result.

Comment: When I tested this, I always ran into the error "An error occurred during the processing of {tenant-relative URL of the page}. Code blocks are not allowed in this file.". Therefore, I decided to follow a similar approach with JavaScript. Nevertheless, thank you very much for pointing me into the right direction!

Comment: Make sure you are uploading the page to a classic site.

Comment: The site I uploaded the page to is a "Team site (classic experience)" according to the admin center.

Answer (score 0):

I decided to implement a redirect page similar to the one suggested by @willman that is using JavaScript to get the query from the k URL parameter, build a new URL that points to /_layouts/15/search.aspx/siteall and /_layouts/15/search.aspx, respectively:

```
<html>

<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        // Get query from URL parameter k
        const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
        const searchQuery = urlParams.get("k");

        if (document.referrer) {
            // Build new URL
            var referrerUrl = new URL(document.referrer);
            var sitePath = "/sites/" + referrerUrl.pathname.split("/")[2];
            var url = "https://ourcompany.sharepoint.com" + sitePath + "/_layouts/15/search.aspx/siteall" + "?q=" +
                searchQuery;

            // Redirect user to new URL
            window.location.replace(url);
        }
    </script>

</head>

<body>
</body>

</html>
```

As I noticed that Internet Explorer neither supports `URLSearchParams` nor `URL()` unfortunately, I'll have to adjust this accordingly before adjusting the search navigation on all sites however.